# Disable default username prompt on connected for vsftpd

Tags: 13.10, ftp, vsftpd

I configured vsftpd on a Ubuntu 13.10 with `anonymous_enable=NO` and `local_enable=YES`, and use my ssh credential to login. The problem is illustrated in this screenshot:

[image]

As you can see my username is shown as default name. I think this is a security problem (I know, I do have a strong password for this username, and adding another layer of obscurity doesn't hurt.) Is there anyway to disable default username prompt? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ftp server is not assuming your username. It's the client that it's sending your actual username as credentials. If I try to log in into your box, I get this (I've blurred your public IP for your own security):

[image]

So I don't think it's a security issue, it only happens because you're not specifying a username, and the system thinks you want to use the same you're already using in the client. Other people login from the outside would have the same error I did.

If you want to increase security, use sftp (ftp over ssh) which will add encryption to the whole client/server communication.

Comment: whoops, that's why I can't search for similar problem. Because It's not a problem. sftp seems really slow in my situation, and anyway I've VPNed into this box so the security should be fine. The attack vector I'm worried about is from outside, but not in the middle.

Comment: It's the same with ssh really. If I try to log-in in my laptop without specifying an username, it will assume the remote user is the one who wants to connect. Of course, I'll need to have the same user accounts in both server and client.

Comment: You can also always try using graphical clients like [gFTP](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gftp/) or [FileZilla](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/filezilla/) - sometimes makes it a bit easier.